# What is the purpose ring counters?

Tags: verilog

Currently, I trying to review the ring counter in verilog.
But I am curious about what is the purpose of ring counter?
I didn't quite catch well. Does anyone know what is the purpose of the ring counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Ring counters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter) four flip-flops can be used to create a four state [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) with no additional logic. A traditional state machine would require 2 flip-flops and next state logic. Wikipedia states that the Ring counter would be simpler and have a smaller synthesis area.

I would expect adder and next state logic required to be of a similar size to the two extra flip-flops used in the ring counter, there making a four state machine of either type roughly equivalent. The ring counter will grow quite quickly as well, each extra state requires an additional flip-flop. and states must always follow a linear pattern. Most FSMs have branches and react to inputs minimising the opportunities to use the ring counter.

The ring counter has the advantage that it state is [one-hot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot). Which might simplify the output logic.

A ring counter FSM:

```
module ring_counter(
  input clk,
  input rst_n,

  //outputs ...
);
reg state0;
reg state1;
reg state2;
reg state3;

always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    state0 <= 1'b1;
    state1 <= 1'b0;
    state2 <= 1'b0;
    state3 <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    state0 <= state3;
    state1 <= state0;
    state2 <= state1;
    state3 <= state2;
  end
end
endmodule
```

The overall state will start as `0001` and then rotate around `0010`, `0100`, `1000` and back to the beginning `0001`.

In comparison a typical FSM could be:

```
reg [1:0] state;

always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    state <= 'b0;
   end
   else begin
     state <= state + 1;
   end
 end
```

Which will iterate through states `00` -> `01` -> `10` -> `11`

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any reference example code regarding ring counter for FSM? I understand almost but I need some example reference for fully understand. Thanks Sir again.